# Преимущества Django перед PHP фреймворками

Tags: python, django

Проясните, пожалуйста, в чем преимущество Django перед PHP фреймворками типа Laravel, Synfony? Как не пытался понять, так и не смог. При этом, насколько знаю, Python и в частности Django работают значительно медленнее PHP и его фреймворков. При этом Django еще не на каждом хостинге можно найти. Что в нем такого уникального, что при всех минусах его продолжают использовать. Понимаю, почему популярен Node.js, его преимущества и почему он отгрыз значительную долю рынка. Но в упор не понимаю, за счет чего выживает Django. Ну не только же в любви к Python дело. Это глупая аргументация для выбора фреймворка. Полагаю, должны быть какие-то более серьезные причины, которые я не могу уловить. Я гуглил, но везде сплошная вода и очень субъективные плюсы, а-ля лучше читается код. Где хоть один существенный, объективный, жирный плюс? Ладно, если даже отбросить скорость работы (хотя интернет говорит, что PHP 7 в разы быстрее работает) и предположить, что она не важна или равна, то есть вообще еще что-то?

Comment: Простота реализации и наличие спецов на рынке, и ночное другое

Comment: @AzizUmarov, как-то очень абстрактно. Вы можете без воды написать объективные плюсы данного фреймворка? Просто тупо по пунктам, но не с стиле - "а мне так нравится", " а мне так удобно". Можете привести хоть один объективный пункт? Я хочу от разбирающихся людей узнать, чем именно так хорош он и Python для web в целом, чего не может предложить PHP и его фреймворки?

Comment: Я не понимаю смысла данного ответа. Рынок диктует спрос и предложение. А не сами фреймворки. Любое + - в миг могут смениться в выходом очередного релиза того или иного. Так что судить чисто по фреймворкам ябы не стал.

Comment: Можно же перевернуть вопрос: "...чем именно так хорош PHP для web в целом, чего не может предложить Python и его фреймворки?", смысл не поменяется. Хотите объективного обзора, но судите, на мой взгляд, предвзято. Чего хотите добиться? Что вы будете делать, когда узнаете ответ на свой вопрос?

Comment: @mrEvgenX, проблема в том, что Python везде пропагандируют, как хороший вариант для перехода с того же php, хотя никаких преимуществ он, похоже, не дает. Складывается впечатление, что популярность Django подкреплена вообще лишь хайпом вокруг Python. Но и этот весь хайп вокруг Python тоже какой-то необоснованный ИМХО.
Просто я не вижу вообще смысла прихода python в web, так как по сути это очередной велосипед, не решающий абсолютно никаких проблем. Те же яйца, только в профиль. Именно в этом моя мысль. Зачем в web еще один "php" не ясно.

Comment: Нода, хотя бы решает одну очевидную проблему - единый язык на беке и фронте. Можно по-разному относиться к JS, но как не крути, удобно писать на одном языке, не переключаясь постоянно с одного синтаксиса на другой. Особенно актуально для фулл-стек девелоперов.
В python в вебе я вижу только один плюс для узкой группы лиц - хороший выход для тех, кто работал на этом языке вне веба, но в какой-то момент понадобился веб, а новый язык учить не хочется.

Comment: Это холивареый вопрос. Вот есть книга Puthon. Разработка на основе тестирования. Прочитай ее и сделай тоже самое на PHP. И почувствуешь разницу. Как и я когда то. Неделю учил php, потом решил попробовать пайтон и вот уже несколько лет это мой основной язык.

Comment: "новый язык учить не хочется" слушайте это бизнес. Вы как работник/сообственник и прочий вариант работаете на рынке услуг. Завтра рынок попросит ОКАКОЙЯЗЫК++ вы будите его изучать или останетесь за бортом. Взрослая жизнь отличается от детства тем что ваши желания остались только там. Во взрослой только компромиссы.

Comment: @alex, но Python в разы медленнее PHP, разве он пригоден для web? PHP сильно распространен, нет проблем с хостингом, вакансиями... Зачем в этом сегменте еще и Python, если PHP справляется лучше? Никак не могу понять. В чем лично вы отмечаете его преимущества именно для web'а?

Comment: PHP - это не про скорость исполнения кода, как и python. Если во главу всего ставится экономия миллисекунд, то PHP в полном пролёте тоже. Когда проект хорошо масштабируется горизонтально (в одном и том же случае этого можно добиться почти на любом языке), не всегда важно как быстро работает сам код, важнее становится, как организовано хранилище данных, кэши и попадание в них, например... А выбор в пользу того или другого языка совершается на основании кучи других факторов, не выйдет это для всех раз и навсегда решить. Вы свой выбор, вижу, сделали и это замечательно :)

Comment: В вопросе я вижу только не вполне рациональное намерение покончить с python только потому, что есть PHP. Как если бы вы пили Coca Cola и отказывались понимать тех, кто говорит про Pepsi. Поправьте меня.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, я просто очень хочу понять мотивацию людей, которые для новых проектов выбирают Python и Django в частности, когда PHP в разы быстрее, с хостингом и его настройкой проще, разработчики недорогие и каких-то видимых функциональных преимуществ, кроме хваленого синтаксиса, что такой себе критерий, так ни от кого и не услышал. Неужели все дело именно в синтаксисе? Я хочу понять, т.к. его позиционируют именно, как замену PHP. Так, может, я что-то упускаю в этой жизни и действительно стоит потратить на него время?

Comment: Лично я позиционирую его не как замену, а как альтернативу. Вот опять, в ваших речах сквозит пренебрежение какое-то, вот видно, что о питонистах вы какого-то невысокого мнения, что это хипстеры и хайпуши какие-то, только и всего. Нельзя так. К тому же вы выбрали не тот сайт, здесь не задают такие вопросы, которые вырастают в такие продолжительные дискуссии:)

Comment: > везде сплошная вода и очень субъективные плюсы, а-ля лучше читается код - это ОФИГЕННЫЙ плюс. А потом, вы же код пишете не для компьютера, а для другого программиста, который будет его читать. Может быть...

Answer (score 1):

Господа,

эта тема может породить очень жаркую дискусиию. Поэтому я - специально для автора вопроса - хочу задать встречный вопрос: а какие критерии он признает "объективными"?

Фактически, дело идет о вкусах.

1. Вы не поверите (и я долго переписывал эту формулировку), но не всем нравится PHP. А выбор чего то, что людям нравится - это большое дело. Грубо говоря, за то, чтобы люди работали на "не клёвой" технологиии и ли на "не клёвом" (можно было написать коротко и по английски - cool) стеке - может понадобиться им платить больше. А может и не понадобиться: вопрос ценообразования всегда сложен.
2. что что то работает быстрее чем что то другое - вообще не аргумент. Ассемблер работет еще быстрее. А вот проект, написанный на нём, чрезвычайно сложен и дорог в поддержке. Node js на сервере - это "бред сумасшедшего" с точки зрения любого сервер - сайд программиста старой школы. Но этот бред стал повсеместно используемым, и позвоялет людям, кторорые знают только js, прекрасно писать полнофункциональные сайты (с котиками).
3. Еще с однйо стороны - можно сравнивать языки. В современном мире все используемые языки более-менее являются мультипарадигменными. И программировать на них можно в любом стиле. Но - грубо говоря, некоторые годятся для того или иного стиля программирования лучше, чем другие. Python был придуман не так давно - всего то десять лет прошло, как начался переход с питона 2 на питон 3. И в нём, как в языке, воплощены наиболее свежие концепции.
4. опять таки, хостинги в том виде, в котором Вы их сравниваете - это не очень объективное сравнение. Есть рынок. На рынке есть много специалистов, которые говорят "наши отцы писали на PHP, наши деды писали на PHP, и мы будем!". Для них специально придуман "PHP хостинг". Он ничем не отличается от любого другого хостинга, кроме слова PHP и, может быть, парочки параметров, которые подкручены на хосте, чтобы немного увеличить производительность.

Но если есть "box" (железка с линуксом) или докер - то любой современный фремворк поднимается несколькими командами. Так что - я бы не стал говорить, что django менее распростарнён.

5. про "великолепную админку" уже написали выше.

И, я еще раз подчеркиваю, нет смысла проводить здесь различия, основанные на вкусах и предпочтениях. Хотя, как вы видите - они есть.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы и разъяснения!

Comment: > а какие критерии он признает "объективными"
Ну, например, Python изначально создавался не только для вэба и, не в первую очередь для него, насколько я понимаю, а PHP именно для вэба и только с этой целью. И на сегодняшний день с этой задачей он справляет лучше и быстрее, а спецы на ранке, наверное, даже дешевле Python спецов.
Вопрос: зачем начинать новый проект на Python, если писать и поддерживать проекты на PHP не сложнее, дешевле, готовых решений больше и работает быстрее?

Comment: Т.е. для чего еще и Python в вэбе, если PHP по многим параметрам выигрышнее? Что такого существенного может предложить мне Python, чтобы мне захотелось делать следующий проект именно на нем? Что он может предложить такого уникального? Только синтаксис?